# Sum with Stirling numbers of first kind

Tags: stirling-numbers

I have problems with proving this equation:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n s_1(n,k)\cdot 2^{k} = (n+1)!$$
where $s_1(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of first kind.

Comment: Note that this is true if $s_1(n,k)$ denotes the unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind. What definition are you using for $s_1(n,k)$? For example, the algebraic definition trivially implies this identity.

Comment: For me it counts permutations of n - element set with k cycles. Though I'm interested in algebraic proof too. What do you mean by algebraic definition? It is that recurrence equation?

Comment: The algebraic definition is as follows: $$
x(x + 1) \cdots (x + n - 1) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n s_1 (n,k)x^k .
$$

Comment: Oh, thank you! This is birlliant, I mean it hadn't came up to my mind to use this equation with raising factorial! Everything's clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a combinatorial proof: Given a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles in cycle notation, write the least element of each cycle first, then construct a permutation of $[n+1]$ by forming a cycle beginning with $n+1$ and choosing for each cycle in $\pi$, in the order of descending first (i.e. least) elements, whether to append it to the cycle. That’s $k$ independent binary choices, so $2^k$ possibilities. You get each permutation of $[n+1]$ exactly once in this way: You can go in the other direction by taking a permutation of $[n+1]$, writing it in cycle notation with $n+1$ as the first element in its cycle, and splitting that cycle at every element that’s less than all preceding elements.